# Gzip compression on Yesod devel

Tags: haskell, middleware, yesod

Where can I turn on gzip compression for a scaffolded Yesod site while running with yesod devel?

http://www.yesodweb.com/book/web-application-interface#web-application-interface_middleware

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to set up the gzip middleware inside yesod devel itself, since it's receiving the HTTP requests from the client. This would be a change to the yesod devel codebase itself. This middleware is not on by default since, on a localhost setup where yesod devel is intended to be used, compressing would almost always be a pessimization.